# Trouble triggering hashchange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why doesn't this cause any logs?

```
addEventListener("hashchange", () => console.log("hash changed"))
history.pushState({}, "", "/#/test")
history.pushState({}, "", "#/test")
```

Also, in React, when using `window.location.href` as a dependency in `useEffect`, a url change doesn't trigger the effect. What's going on?

Comment: I mean, you are clearly setting a history state and not a hash? It looks like a hash, sure, but to the page this is just a fake url pasted over your current one, not a change in hash.